# ES6 Modules: Sustainability of TypeScript internal modules & Bundles

Tags: module, typescript, ecmascript-6

### Full names of classes in TypeScript

TypeScript 1.X allows the developer to use internal modules as namespaces.

```
module MyProject.MySubProject {
    export class A {
    }
    export function f() {
        var a1 = new A(); // valid
        var a2 = new MySubProject.A(); // valid too
        var a3 = new MyProject.MySubProject.A(); // valid too, again
    }
}
MyProject.MySubProject.f();
var a4 = new MyProject.MySubProject.A(); // ... and valid
```

When transpiled to ES5, this code creates an object `MyProject` that contains an object `MySubProject` that contains two functions `A` and `f`.

From inside the module, a class can be designed with a relative name (`A`, `MySubProject.A`) or the full name (`MyProject.MySubProject.A`). From outside the module, the exported class is used with the full name.

But [nested modules no longer exists in ES6](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html). And TypeScript [is going to align to the ES6 modules](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#15).

Are the full names of classes (`MyModule1.MyModule2.MyClass`) compatible to ES6?

If we want to use namespaces in the old way, can we declare an ES6 class in a closure or an object?

### Bundles and ES6 modules

Here is a similar code in the ES6 way:

```
//------ MyProject/MySubProject.js ------
export class A {
}
export function f() {
    var a1 = new A(); // valid
}

//------ main.js ------
import { A, f } from 'MyProject/MySubProject';
f();
var a2 = new A();
```

After concatenation of the two JavaScript files into a single minified file, how to operate the `import`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript is only going to align with ES6 modules as a *new* sytanx *based on* `TypeScript external modules`. This is based off of what work is being done on GitHub. Current *internal* modules do not conflict with the new syntax and therefore will continue to work as is.

Comment: Thank you. Now, if ES6 classes can't be nested in a closure, then the TS internal modules aren't perennial. Because, when the target is ES6, the compiler should transpile TS classes to ES6 classes, shouldn't it?

Comment: I'm totally lost with all this.. I'm willing to use TS for my app's code, ES6 and jspm; can I use TypeScript internal modules or should I just use the external modules in TypeScript?

Comment: Just use external mdoules